# Compton Scattering in One Dimension

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics

In Principles of Quantum Mechanics by Shankar p. 123, he discusses that the momentum of a particle in the momentum state $|p\rangle$ can be measured by *Compton scattering*, in which a photon of definite momentum bounces off the particle.

He further wrote,

---

Assume the particle is forced to move along the x-axis and that we send in a right-moving photon of energy $\hbar\omega$ that bounces off the particle and returns as a left-moving photon of energy $\hbar\omega'$. Using momentum and energy conservation,

$$cp' = cp + \hbar(\omega + \omega')\\
  E' = E + \hbar(\omega - \omega')$$

where $p$ is the momentum of the particle and $E$ is its energy. It is now possible from this data to reconstruct the initial and final momenta of the
particle,

$$cp = -\frac{(\hbar\omega + \hbar\omega')}{2} + \sqrt{1 + \frac{m^2 c^4}{\hbar^2\omega\omega'}} \frac{(\hbar\omega - \hbar\omega')}{2}\\
cp' = \frac{(\hbar\omega + \hbar\omega')}{2} + \sqrt{1 + \frac{m^2 c^4}{\hbar^2\omega\omega'}} \frac{(\hbar\omega - \hbar\omega')}{2}.$$

---

How can I get the last equations for the initial and final momenta? Using the relativistic energy $E^2 = m^2c^4 + p^2c^2$ of the particle and solving the system of equations does not yield the result claimed by Shankar. Are the results presented by Shankar wrong? Are there any other references for these equations?

Comment: Since you have already found the initial and the final momenta of a particle, it is not clear what the question is.

Comment: @Vadim I have rephrased my sentence. I cannot derive it from the conservation laws.

Comment: But this is where your expressions come from - didn't you derive them yoruself? Apart from that: it is a system of two equations with two unknowns: you exclude one unknown, solve for the other, and then use the result to also find the excluded one.

Comment: @Vadim I did not derive it, that is exactly my question, I do not know how Shankar got those expressions. I also know that it is a system of two equations with two unknowns but I tried solving for it but cannot reproduce the result.

Comment: You are essentially asking that somebody does math for you... there is no conceptual question here.

Comment: @Vadim Maybe I'm missing some equations that he assumes that I know. AFAIK, the relativistic energy can be used.

Comment: If you substitute the expression for the relativistic energy into the second equation, you have two equations with two unknowns - nothing is missing there.